# CMS block doesn't appear although called in template (Magento)

Tags: magento

I have tried to add a static CMS block inside a template. Here's what I've used

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('gift')->toHtml() ?>
```

But then, when I clear the cache and also, delete all files in  **var/cache** folder, this block doesn't appear on the page.

I looked into the database and saw the correct relationship between block id and store id. This block is also active.

What should I do to make this block appear on a page? Is there anything else I need to look further into?

Thank you very much.

Comment: That looks right.  Which phtml file are you trying this in?

Comment: Make sure that your Static Block store view is set correctly for your current view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is correct.

1. Check that the identifier you set on your static block is 'gift'
2. Verify that $this->getLayout() is working correctly. Namely, make sure you are using the code on a template file.
3. Verify your static block has content.
4. If all else fails, enable logging and check error log. Enable template/path hints and check those.

Comment: Thank you. I have traced the log and I found that the code in CMS block is causing an error. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have a relation between the CMS Static Block and the store in the database table cms_block_store